# Assert OutputStreamWriter contains correct instance of OutputStream

Tags: java, assert, outputstream, writer

I'm writing a test for a method that returns `Writer` for different extension files.

For `.gz` returns `new OutputStreamWriter(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

For non compressed files returns `new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

How to assert that OutputStreamWriter contains `GZIPOutputStream` or `FileOutputStream`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OutputStreamWriter extends Writer. Your FileOutputStream or GZIPOutputStream is set as: protected Object lock inside Writer class.

```
 OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("file_patch")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Field lock = outputStreamWriter.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("lock");
    lock.setAccessible(true);
    Object o = lock.get(outputStreamWriter);
    Class<?> theClassYouNeed = o.getClass();
```

Now you just need to check if theClassYouNeed is the expected class.